# Can't insert custom snippets in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I recently came to know about the RStudio [snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets-in-the-RStudio-IDE) and am trying to implement it to make my code look neat. I created the following snippets via the Edit Snippets button in Global Options -> Code

```
snippet shead
#***********************************************************************
#   ${1:title} ----
#***********************************************************************

snippet sdiv
#   ${1} ----

snippet ssdiv
#   ├   ${1} ----
```

But for some reason, I can't insert them in my code - When I try to insert them using tab (or control+space) I can't see any matches in the completion list. But I can see other snippets like, for example, shinyapp snippet. I tried updating RStudio to the latest version (2022-04-19 release for macOS), but it doesn't help. Does anybody know what's the problem here?

Comment: You should have a tab (a real tab, not two spaces), below the snippet lines, does this help ?

Comment: I tried with tab (instead of spaces). Doesn't change anything